# Sort array with uasort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I’m working on a little PHP function that will sort an array based off of if the item returned `isVerified` or not. If it is in fact verified, I'd like those results to be displayed at the top of the list. I admit I’m not the most familiar with PHP and I’ve been doing a lot of reading up since I figured there could possibly be a method to make this easier. Reading around it sounded like the uasort() was what I needed for its sorting abilities and that it maintains index association, but I’m a little confused as how to properly use it. The original block of PHP I am working on looks like this:

```
<?php
  if (count($results)):

  $lexisIndex = 1;

  foreach ($results as $person){
    $person->isVerified = (substr($person->first_name, 0, 1) == substr($fname, 0, 1) && $person->last_name == $lname );                                     
    $person->lexisIndex = $lexisIndex++;
  }

  foreach ($results as $person):
?>
```

From here I put the `$results` into an array and passed it into a uasort function. After I added what I thought I needed the code looked like this:

```
<?php
    if (count($results)):

        $lexisIndex = 1;

        foreach ($results as $person){
            $person->isVerified = (substr($person->first_name, 0, 1) ==  substr($fname, 0, 1) && $person->last_name == $lname );
            $person->lexisIndex = $lexisIndex++;
        }

        $array = array($results);

        uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a < $b ? -1 : 1);
    });

    foreach ($results as $person):
?>
```

This still didn't work for me and didn't throw any errors so I'm having a heck of a time trying to work this one out. Am I on the right track with what I'm using? Or can this be done in a more efficient manner? I apologize if this is sounds like a question that has been asked before, but I couldn't find a fix while searching around. If this is a duplicate I'm more than happy to click a link and do some more reading. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are the elements of the array. So in your case, they are person objects, and that's how you should compare them:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    // isVerified is most important. Move to top.
    if ($a->isVerified != $b->isVerified ) {
      return ($a->verified ? -1 : 1);
    }
    // If neither or both are verified, compare based on lexisindex.
    return $a->lexisIndex - $b->lexisIndex;
});
```

The last line is just a shortcut. A comparison function doesn't need to return -1, 0 or 1. It just accepts any value < 0 to indicate that `$a` is 'smaller' than `$b`, 0 for equality or > 0 for `larger`. So your current compare callback, which would compare numeric values, could also just be written as `return $a - $b;`. You could also write the last line like this, but it's not necessary:

```
return ($a->lexisIndex < $b->lexisIndex ? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: Ah there it is! Thank you so much for that code and the explanation on what's going on behind it. It worked perfect.